# How does the tf.train.batch_join() function in tensorflow work?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to train a neural network in tensorflow. I load the data along with its labels using the tf.train.batch_join() fucntion. I do something like this:

```
image_batch, label_batch, image_batch_f = tf.train.batch_join(
        images_and_labels, batch_size=batch_size_placeholder,
        #shapes=[(args.image_size, args.image_size, 3), ()], enqueue_many=True,
        shapes=[(args.image_height, args.image_width, 3), (), (args.image_height, args.image_width, 3)], enqueue_many=True,
        capacity=4 * nrof_preprocess_threads * args.batch_size,
        allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
    image_batch = tf.identity(image_batch, 'image_batch')
    image_batch = tf.identity(image_batch, 'input')
    label_batch = tf.identity(label_batch, 'label_batch')
    image_batch_f = tf.identity(image_batch_f, 'flipped_images_batch')
```

Here, I get three batches of data. A batch of images, a batch of labels and a batch of flipped images of the same images as in the batch of images. I want to extract features on the batch of images and flipped images. The lines below pass the batches of data through the network.

```
    # Build the inference graph
    prelogits, _ = network.inference(image_batch, args.keep_probability,
        phase_train=phase_train_placeholder, feature_dimension=args.embedding_size,
        weight_decay=args.weight_decay)


    features = tf.nn.l2_normalize(prelogits, 1, 1e-10, name='embeddings')

    #getting the flipped embeddings
    prelogits_f, _ = network.inference(image_batch_f,args.keep_probability,
                    phase_train=phase_train_placeholder,feature_dimension=args.embedding_size,
                    weight_decay=args.weight_decay,reuse=True)
    features_flipped_images = tf.nn.l2_normalize(prelogits_f,1,1e-10,name='embeddings_f')
```

For getting both the features, I run a session.run() on the features and features_flipped_images ops. Something like this:

```
feed_dict = {phase_train_placeholder:False, batch_size_placeholder:batch_size}
emb, emb_f = sess.run([features, features_flipped_images],feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

My question is the following. I am guessing when I do a session run on the features, that is when the batch_join function will dispatch a batch of images of size batch_size. But then when I do a session.run() on the features_flipped_images, that function will also get a batch of flipped images from the batch_join function. Does the batch_join function dispatch a fresh batch of flipped images when features_flipped_images is executed? Or is it the same batch of flipped images which was generated when features was executed? If not then how do I do this? I want to extract features on the batch of images and a batch of flipped images.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is each run [features, features_flipped_images] will only get the same batch of data. Let's take an example:

```
imgs_batch,labels_batch = tf.train.batch([img, label]...)
```

then, if you want to see what's in the batch:

```
imgs_data, labels_data = sess.run([imgs_batch, labels_batch])
```

you see, it's similar when you run sess.run([features, features_flipped_images],..). I don't think you will get two batches, otherwise, the imgs_data and labels_data are not correspondence to each other.

Comment: I am not sure if its the same batch because if I concatenate the features for images and flipped images and use the concatenated feature for matching, the performance of my system is dropping significantly when it should actually be improving the matching performance. I am still unclear about the batch loader.